# filter data frame based on id and date range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, `df`, containing `ID` and `date` columns:

```
start = datetime.datetime.today()
dates = [start, start+relativedelta(days=20), start+relativedelta(days=40),
         start, start+relativedelta(days=35), start+relativedelta(days=36),
         start, start+relativedelta(days=10), start+relativedelta(days=15)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 'date':dates})

   ID                       date
0   1 2018-11-29 15:35:56.876549
1   1 2018-12-19 15:35:56.876549
2   1 2019-01-08 15:35:56.876549
3   2 2018-11-29 15:35:56.876549
4   2 2019-01-03 15:35:56.876549
5   2 2019-01-04 15:35:56.876549
6   3 2018-11-29 15:35:56.876549
7   3 2018-12-09 15:35:56.876549
8   3 2018-12-14 15:35:56.876549
```

Now I want to filter `df` so that for every ID, only the first 30 days are included. I.e. date <= (date.min() + 30 days)

This means for example ID=1, 2019-01-08 is more than 30 days after the first date, 2018-11-29, so it should be removed. And so on. The resulting new dataframe should be:

```
   ID                       date
0   1 2018-11-29 15:35:56.876549
1   1 2018-12-19 15:35:56.876549
3   2 2018-11-29 15:35:56.876549
6   3 2018-11-29 15:35:56.876549
7   3 2018-12-09 15:35:56.876549
8   3 2018-12-14 15:35:56.876549
```

How can this be done programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding helper columns for *start* and *end* dates, then run boolean indexing for filter. Specifically, use `groupby().tansform` for inline `min` aggregation:

```
df['start_date'] = df.groupby(df['ID'])['date'].transform('min')
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + relativedelta(days=30)

# BOOLEAN MASK
sub_df = df[(df['date'] >= df['start_date']) & (df['date'] <= df['end_date'])]
print(sub_df)
#    ID                       date                 start_date                   end_date
# 0   1 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 1   1 2018-12-19 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 3   2 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 6   3 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 7   3 2018-12-09 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 8   3 2018-12-14 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788

# WITH BETWEEN()
sub_df = df[df['date'].between(df['start_date'], df['end_date'])]
print(sub_df)
#    ID                       date                 start_date                   end_date
# 0   1 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 1   1 2018-12-19 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 3   2 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 6   3 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 7   3 2018-12-09 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 8   3 2018-12-14 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788

# WITH QUERY()
sub_df = df.query('date >= start_date & date <= end_date')
print(sub_df)
#    ID                       date                 start_date                   end_date
# 0   1 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 1   1 2018-12-19 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 3   2 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 6   3 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 7   3 2018-12-09 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
# 8   3 2018-12-14 15:22:35.301788 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788 2018-12-29 15:22:35.301788
```

For clean-up of helper columns:

```
# DROP HELPER COLUMNS
sub_df = sub_df.drop(columns=['start_date', 'end_date'])
print(sub_df)
#    ID                       date
# 0   1 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788
# 1   1 2018-12-19 15:22:35.301788
# 3   2 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788
# 6   3 2018-11-29 15:22:35.301788
# 7   3 2018-12-09 15:22:35.301788
# 8   3 2018-12-14 15:22:35.301788
```